# How to apply material to mesh in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, textures

ANSWER: I had to apply the textures to my meshes in Sketchup and then re-apply them in Unity after importing.

I'm attempting to apply materials to meshes in Unity 5. In the image, I have applied the same material to two different meshes. The image is wood grain and displays as desired on the right. On the left, the same material appears as solid brown. I want it to look the same as the material on the right.

The meshes are imported from Sketchup. This happens in many cases using different textures on different meshes.

I have grouped the meshes and put them in components in Sketchup, but this doesn't appear to effect the outcome.

Even on simple shapes that match approximately the height/width ratio of the image being used for the texture, this effect appears.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the other meshes are not flipped?

Comment: I don't think so - but the material looks the same on both sides anyway

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved this. I had to apply the textures to my meshes in Sketchup and then re-apply them in Unity after importing. If I create an object in Sketchup and try to apply the material in Unity, it doesn't work. But if I apply the texture in Sketchup, import it into Unity (the material will not appear on the object initially), then drag the image or material onto the object, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the item on the left is much larger than the item on the right.
The material is probably getting stretched making it appear solid brown.

Try adjusting the tiling of the texture. You're probably going to need more than one material

Comment: yes - I've tried tiling, and the left mesh is bigger. I tried breaking the meshes up into much simpler, smaller shapes that are similar in aspect ratio to the texture image, but no help. Notice the door in the back - its a rectangle and accepts the material in the same way as the wall in the foreground. The wall in the foreground is much larger and has a very irregular shape, but the texture still works as expected.